# Extension of an Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose $E_1, E_2 \subset E$ are proper subfields. In general, if one has an isomorphism $\sigma:E_1\to E_2$, is it possible to extend it to an isomorphism $\psi:E\to E$ s.t. $\psi|_{E_1} = \sigma$ ?

Ideally, is it possible to get such a $\psi$ that also does not "affect" elements in $E\backslash E_1$ ? I thought
$$
\psi(e):=\begin{cases} e, & e \in E\backslash E_1, \\ \sigma(e), & e \in E_1,\end{cases}
$$
might work but unfortunately it looks like it does not in general.

Comment: No, there is no such way to not affect things in the complement (in general). Let $x\in E\setminus E_1$ and consider $\sigma:E_1\to E_2$ such that $\sigma(e_0)\ne e_0$. Then if the extended $\sigma$ doesn't affect $x$, i.e. $\sigma(x)=x$ we have $\sigma(x+e_0)=x+\sigma(e_0)\ne x+e_0$ so $\sigma$ messes up something else.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if  $E$ is an algebraic and normal  extension of the fixed subfield of the morphism $E_1\to E_2$, but not in general.

Here is an example when you can't extend. Consider $E = \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{2}})\ $, 
$E_1 = E_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) $ and $E_1 \to E_2$, $\sqrt{2} \mapsto - \sqrt{2}$.

Let's show the existence of an extension. There are two fundamental facts about algebraic extensions of fields.

1. If $E/E_1$ is an algebraic extension then any $E_1 \to F$ is a morphism to an algebraically closed field $F$ can be extended to a morphism from $E$ to $F$.
2. Let $E/E'$ an algebraic normal extension and $F\supset E$ an extension of $E$. Let $\phi \colon E \to F$ a morphism of fields such that $\phi_{|E'} = Id_{E'}$. Then $\phi(E) = E$.

We are ready for the proof: Consider an extension of the morphism $E_1\to E_2$ from $E$ to an algebraic closure of $E$. Since the extesion $E/E'$ is algebraic and normal image of $E$ will conincide with $E$. Done.

Comment: May I dare ask how it can be extended when $E$ is normal over $E_1\cap E_2$? Also, is the hypothesis that $E$ is normal over $E_1\cap E_2$ necessary to be able to extend $\sigma$ ? Nice example, thank you.

Comment: Oh, the counterexample given shows in fact that $E$ normal over $E_1\cap E_2$ is not enough;  however, a stronger condition is enough: $E$ normal over the fixed subfield of the map $E_1 \to E_2$. I corrected that in the answer. I will provide details on why it can be extended in that case.